# MoveMemory Byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, memory, byte

I'm using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define address 0x00401054

int main(){
    byte values[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8 };
    MoveMemory((*(PVOID*)address), values[0], 4);
}
```

But return this error

**IntelliSense: argument of type "byte" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void ***

what to do?

Comment: If `address` is actually an address, use `MoveMemory((PVOID*)address, values, 4);`

Comment: @DouglasRodrigues: You can't access graphics memory this way. In Windows you do not have the graphics adapter at a fixed address.

Comment: Let's just assume `address` were valid within the calling process. Why is it being casted to `PVOID*` (`void**`) and then dereferenced, instead of being casted to `PVOID` (`void*`) and not dereferenced?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. And i'm sorry for any problem.
Thank you @dasblinkenlight and Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&values[0]` to take the *address* of the first element of your array.

Or, just use `values` by itself (instead of `&values[0]`), because the name of an array refers to the address of its first element.